# iPhone - Add UIImage to Folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, jpeg

I have a folder called PhotoSet in my Xcode iOS App. I want to convert the UIImage to a jpg and put it into the folder. Here is what I have so far (by the way, if it is at all relevant, the UIImage is taken from a photo that the user takes):

```
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1.0);
if (imageData != nil) {
    [imageData writeToFile:@"/Users/Toly/Desktop/PhotoMap/PhotoMap/PhotoSet/test.jpg" atomically:YES];
}
```

I get no errors or warnings. However, no picture gets saved to any folder. What should I do?

Comment: Do you think that your iPhone has such a directory structure (hint: it does not)? Did you check the return value of the call to `writeToFile:`? You need to write to a valid path within your app's sandbox. Do some searching. That has been covered many times here.

Comment: Simulator should actually save image to desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write to a directory that is actually on the iPhone. Most of the time you'll want to write to the documents directory. You can get the path to it like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

This gives you the base documents directory, if you want to place the folder in a sub directory you'll need to create that folder before you do like so.

```
NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAddingPathComponent:@"myFolder/images"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init]
[fm createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Then to save your image data to that folder you'll do something like this

```
NSString *imageDataPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage"];
BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:imageDataPath];
```

Also, you can NSLog the imageDataPath it'll give you the exact location that file is saved so you can navigate to the actual file in finder if you're using the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone does not contain a data structure of files mirroring "/Users/Toly/Desktop/PhotoMap/PhotoMap/PhotoSet/test.jpg"

If you want the image to persist in memory, try using nsuserdefaults, or xcassets or Coredata. If you are absolutely intent on writing to a file,  check out the NSCoding and NSFileManager tutorial below:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data

Comment: Do not use `NSUserDefaults` to persist an image. Write it to a file.